# Recover data on a hard-drive that changed partition table

Tags: hard-drive, gpt, gparted, mbr

I changed the partition table on one HDD from GPT to MBR/MSDOS but I realized (too late) that it affected all partitions on the same HDD. Basically I lost data on the secondary partition which I wanted to keep.

I used gparted to perform the change of partition type.

How can I recover the data I had on my secondary partition? Nothing has been formatted, I've "only" changed the partition table (i.e. I guess destroy the previous partition table).

Recovering the data that was loosed is of more importance than getting to a HDD with MBR at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: It should go without saying, but I'll say it anyway: You're going to keep backups of all your important data from now on, right? (you happen to be very lucky this time: [*you can recover from this one*](http://serverfault.com/a/489165/32986))

Answer (score 1):

If you (somehow) remember/backed up  the previous PT, then just recreating it with the same layout should cut it **IF** you did not write to the disk. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: I've not written to the disk after the PT was changed. However, I don't have a PT backup...

Comment: Uh. Then this: http://forum.onmac.net/showthread.php?t=136 is an URL I would start with. GPT Keeps multiple backups of its data structures plus  a Protective MBR, so you should be able to get it back - 'dd' your disk content somewhere before touching it again tho'.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use testdisk to recover partition table and files. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aidfile Recovery software, which is a powerful partition recovery tool for restore files from size or type changed partition drives. It supports EXFAT / FAT32 / NTFS file systems.